# what is the equivalent of \reserveinserts in latex 2015

Tags: etoolbox, latex-base, e-tex

The release 2015 of LaTeX has included features of the `etex.sty` package. However, it does not have included the `\reserveinserts` command.

My questions is very simple: what is the mechanism to use to have the same feature as `\reserveinserts`.

My other question is: does http://latex-project.org/ltnews/ltnews22.pdf the correct file which explain this change?

Comment: eledmac specifies a whole load of packages twice (xargs,etoolbox,suffix,xstring,etoolbox,ifluatex,ragged2e} and does `\reserveinserts{32}` twice so allocating 64 inserts. It would be better if it just specified the packages once, and did `\ifx\reserveinserts\@undefined\else\reserveinserts{32}\fi`

Comment: I have corrected the bug for loading twice time package in the last version (1.23.1). I will add the test on \reserveinserts. Many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should not need to use `\reserveinserts` at all. If you need an insert just use `\newinsert` and allocate one.

This isn't really a change, so is not mentioned in latex news 22. `\reserveinserts` was not previously in the format so the fact that it is not in the format now is not a change, and if you load `etex.sty` then that package's allocation will still be used, and `\reserveinserts` will work as before.

So the only change is that in most cases it is now better not to load the `etex` package and instead use the format allocation macros.

Comment: so the need of \reserveinserts is not more required because of the change ? but for the user who used previous version of LaTeX, it was useful to prevent conflitc?

Comment: (ps : in my case, the problem is that I was loading etex via etoolbox, and etoolbox now don't load it.)

Comment: @Maïeul it wasn't very useful as far as I can see:-) If there is a plausible use case I could add something to `elocalloc` which is adding some other less used bits of etex.sty back, but currently I don't see any real need.

Comment: @Maïeul OK so that's a change in etoolbox rather than in latex, so documented in that package's documentation rather than ltnews.

Comment: @Maïeul even if a user is using a big class like memoir then `\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{eledmac}` there are over 50 inserts available for `\newseries` on the other hand if the user has `\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz,pstricks}
\usepackage{eledmac}` then the dimens have been allocated anyway so it would not have been possible to reserve them, and you need to load eledmac earlier.

Comment: ok. So the good solution in this case will to inform user to use \reserveinsert? I don't remember exactly when I needed to add this \reservinsert in eledmac. I will look to the history to understand exactly what is the need.

Comment: @Maïeul no `\reserveinserts` is not defined by default, so don't tell the user to use that, I added a code suggestion just now as a comment on the question)

Comment: I have look to the problem for which I needed \reserveinserts. It is on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maieul/ledmac/8570276dfd5f390ec140db3874a1cd54c56b8154/issue108.tex. So the problem is when using a lot of counter. But it seems `\reserveinserts`  was not a good solution to solve it.

Comment: @Maïeul that is same as pstricks example I posted above `\reserveinserts` wouldn't have helped anyway as you already used up too many counters before your package loaded, just move eledmac before biblatex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24229/discussion-between-maieul-and-david-carlisle).